# How to build a code with x86 jdk when my pc just installed x64 jdk7

Tags: java, maven

I need to build  my program(maven) to 2 packages (x86 and x64 ) in myeclipse 2014, just like visual studio can do.anyone know how to handle this situation?

Comment: There is no such thing as a x86 or x64 jar. Java is compiled into the Java Machine IS. At this point there is only one Java instruction set.

Comment: Yes, all Jar files use the exact same byte codes.  There's no difference (to the user, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compiles to a single cross-platform byte code. You are running it on a 64 bit JRE, JVM, but that is irrelevant.

The only (rare) issue arises when incorporating *native* libraries (say programmed in C/C++), then there are separate DDLs for Windows x64 and x86, and for Linux.

Comment: Just a small addition: while they're platform-independent, class file formats do however differ between different Java versions (8,7,6,etc.), and you can control the output format by passing the `-target` option to `javac`.

Comment: @biziclop yes for instance with Java 8 JDK you could **target 1.7** for java 7 customers. Though you should test run too under a JRE 7 for version incompatibilities. For instance at one time the zip API got an extra optional parameter for character encoding of entry names.

Answer (score 0):

finally ,I solver this queresion like below:

1. I install a x86 jdk7,and add it to myeclipse JreLibrary
2. config the swt x86  user library(org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.6.2.v3659c.jar)
3. pacakge twice with diffrent jdk and user library

@Joop Eggen thanks for your help